# Injecting a viewmodel into another

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Is it possible to inject a `ViewModel` into another when using `Hilt` with `Jetpack Compose`?

I am getting this error when I try to do so.

> Injection of an @HiltViewModel class is prohibited since it does not
> create a ViewModel instance correctly.   Access the ViewModel via the
> Android APIs (e.g. ViewModelProvider) instead.   Injected ViewModel:
> <package_name>.MainActivityViewModel

**Scenario**
I have screen-specific ViewModels for all the screens and an Activity ViewModel for common data and logic required throughout the app.

Currently, to communicate from my screen-specific ViewModel to the activity ViewModel, I have to change data (live data, flow, or mutable state) which is being observed in the screen composable and based on that data change, the composable triggers the required data or action from the activity ViewModel.

Is there a direct way to do this?
Communication from screen-specific ViewModel to activity ViewModel?

Sample code,

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ScreenSpecificViewModel @Inject constructor(
    // private val activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel, - This results in error
    private val repo: Repo,
) : BaseViewModel() {
    private val _resultLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val resultLiveData: LiveData<String>
        get() = _resultLiveData
 
    fun someApiCall() {
        val result = repo.apiCall()
        _navigationRouteLiveData.postValue(result)
    }
}
```

**Composable**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenView(
    screenViewModel: ScreenSpecificViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel,
) {
    val result by screenViewModel.resultLiveData.observeAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = result,
    ) {
        result?.let { value ->
            activityViewModel.setData(value)
        }
    }
    // Other code
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good way of organization to create view models that depend on other view models, I imagine that the ideal thing is for you to inject only the common repositories to the view models separately (each view model calling the same repository) and then the 2 view models able to communicate with the data. If you want to follow a cleaner architecture, you could also inject the same "use case" into each view model in isolation without one view model having to depend directly on the other.

Comment: "2 view models able to communicate with the data" - Exactly what I am doing at the moment. It's just that it feels like a lot of unnecessary data .